# How do I save multiple checkbox values in a single column in the database and retrieve it using laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, checkbox, crud

I have 15 Checkbox at my admin panel so only website admin can select or cancel them.

I need to save checkbox's that checked at my table like this:

```
Name: car,food,game,...
```

HTML:

```
{{Form::open(['action'=>'adminHobbyController@store'])}}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="art" class="checkbox-inline">
            {{Form::checkbox('art[]','art')}}Art
         </label>
         <label for="artitecture" class="checkbox-inline">        
              {{Form::checkbox('artitecture[]','artitecture')}}Artitecture
         </label>
          <label for="business" class="checkbox-inline">
              {{Form::checkbox('business[]','business')}}Business
          </label>
              ...
          <div class="form-group">
              {{Form::submit('ADD',['class'=>'form-control'])}} 
          </div>
 {{Form::close()}}
```

My Controller Store Function :

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $add_hobby=new Hobbies;
    $add_hobby->name=$request->all();
    $add_hobby->save();
    return redirect()->back();
 }
```

Also try this but only save the last one :

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $add_hobby=new Hobbies;
    $add_hobby->name=$request->input('car');
    $add_hobby->name=$request->input('food');
      ...
   $add_hobby->name=$request->input('fashion');
    $add_hobby->save();
    return redirect()->back();
 }
```

I tried this too but I got Error :

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->merge([
    'name' => implode(',', (array) $request->input('game')),
    'name' => implode(',', (array) $request->input('food')),
      ...
      'name' => implode(',', (array) $request->input('fashion')),
]);

    $add_hobby=new Hobbies;
    $add_hobby->name=$request->input()->all();
    $add_hobby->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Anyone can help?

Of course is not necessary save at one column but also i don't know another way to save them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating multiple arrays by doing this

```
{{Form::checkbox('art[]','art')}}Art
```

Insted of `art[]` use seomthing like `hobby[]` and then put `art` as the value

Try this

```
    <label for="art" class="checkbox-inline">
        {{Form::checkbox('hobby[]','art')}}Art
     </label>
     <label for="artitecture" class="checkbox-inline">        
          {{Form::checkbox('hobby[]','artitecture')}}Artitecture
     </label>
      <label for="business" class="checkbox-inline">
          {{Form::checkbox('hobby[]','business')}}Business
      </label>
          ...
      <div class="form-group">
          {{Form::submit('ADD',['class'=>'form-control'])}} 
      </div>
```

And then in your controller you would go something like

```
foreach ($request->input("hobby") as $hobby){
        $add_hobby = new Hobbies;
        $add_hobby->name= $hobby;
        $add_hobby->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do a simple step to save this in a one shot.

```
 <label for="art" class="checkbox-inline">
    {{Form::checkbox('art','art')}}Art
 </label>
 <label for="artitecture" class="checkbox-inline">        
      {{Form::checkbox('artitecture','artitecture')}}Artitecture
 </label>
  <label for="business" class="checkbox-inline">
      {{Form::checkbox('business','business')}}Business
  </label>
      ...
  <div class="form-group">
      {{Form::submit('ADD',['class'=>'form-control'])}} 
  </div>
```

And then in your controller,

```
$hobby = implode(",",array_keys($request->except(['_method','_token'])))
//Exclude the parameters from the $request using except() method
//now in your $hobby variable, you will have "art,artitecture,business"

$add_hobby=new Hobbies;
$add_hobby->name=$hobby;
$add_hobby->save();
```

Dont forget to exclude the data that you dont need for hobbies.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the implode method and store it in a variable then assign it to the column.

```
$add_hobby->[column]= $array_imploded;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that column in which you want to store those values is varchar or text and can store all the text you'll put there.

Second, make a JSON string out from your values. (Or serialized array string but JSON is better to read). Then just store this setting as a string and do not forget to parse JSON back to an array when you access this data.

This links will help you a bit:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

and for the case, you pick a seralized array:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php